# getting url from action.view intent

Tags: android, android-intent

My android app shows the below exception on click.

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle 
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com (has extras) }
```

Can anyone tell me as to how to obtain the data "www.google.com" from intent? If I'm able to obtain that data, **I can handle the next activity by opening a webview and load the URI that I obtain from the intent.**

Comment: Can you provide the code to show how you are starting the activity? Also, if you would provide a copy of your android manifest, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url should be preceeded by `http//`, if you set "www.google.com" it won't identify the url. Your url should be like this  `http://www.google.com`  , I hope this will help you.